# how to set date condition in fast refresh method on MVIEW

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I'd like to create MVIEWs by fast refresh method, but it's have more restriction. One of them is not contains non-repeatable expression (SYSDATE). If I want to get current date, Can I define it in any other way?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mview_load
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
    SELECT ID,NUMBER_SHIPMENT,NUMBER_STOP,CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE
    FROM LOAD
    WHERE CREATE_DATE >= SYSDATE-1
```

Comment: If you are only concerned about the date part and not the time part, store the sysdate in a separate table and try selecting it from that table. You can have a daily job to refresh the date at 12:00 AM daily.

Comment: Hi @ArtBajji, I already created success!!!. by you way to be a part.  Moreover, I define rowid of load and rowid of table's store sysdate in SELECT section. Thank you so much.